# join two columns in a dataframe so they do not contain same values

Tags: r

Sooo

I’ve got two lists

```
list1 <- rep(c("john","steve","lisa","sara","anna"), c(50,0,15,25,10))
list2 <- rep(c("john","steve","lisa","sara","anna"), c(15,25,0,10,50))
```

I need to put them into a dataframe.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1, nrow = 100, ncol = 2))
df$v1 <- list1
```

Now the problem.

I need to put list2 into df$v2
with out any row in df containing the same values.
It does not matter what values are in each row.

I use this for testing it, if each rows contains the same value:

```
all(apply(ballots, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 2) == TRUE)
```

to clarify:

I need each value in the columns, which row doesn't matter.
I need a way to randomize or change the order of the second column (or the first) in such a way that the same value is never in column one or two

The output:

```
V1      V2
John    Steve
John    Lisa
Sara    John
John    Lisa
Steve   Anna
```

Currently, when I join the columns in the dataframe, there are many rows in both column one and two containing the same value.

Comment: So you want to return `NA` if it contains same value?

Comment: I see I need to clarify.
No I need each value in the column, where doesn't matter.
I need a way to randomize or change the order of the second column in such a way that the same value is never in column one or two

Comment: please post wanted output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright... finally found the answer after many trials and errors.

If anyone has a cleaner method to do this I would love to see one.

The following code takes list A and puts it in column A
takes list B, randomizes and puts in column C, Column B is NA
If A and C is not the same, switch column B and C.
If it fails to finish all the rows, it starts over, randomizing column C

```
library(taRifx)

failed.counter <- 0

while (failed.counter <= 1) {
list1 <- rep(c("A","B","C"), c(3,1,2))
list2 <- sample(rep(c("A","B","C"), c(2,3,1)))


df <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(list1), ncol = 3))
df[,1] <- list1
df[,3] <- list2
iteration.counter <- 0

while (anyNA(df$V2) == TRUE && failed.counter == 0 ) {       
        iteration.counter <- iteration.counter + 1
        df.sub <- df[is.na(df[,2]) & df[,1] != df[,3] & !is.na(df[,3]),]
        df.sub <- df.sub[,c("V1", "V3", "V2")]
        colnames(df.sub) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
        r.names <- rownames(df.sub)
       df[r.names,] <- df.sub 

       df[,3] <- shift(df[,3], 1, Wrap=TRUE)
       if(iteration.counter >= nrow(df)+1) {failed.counter <- 1}

}
if(anyNA(df$V2) == FALSE) {failed.counter <- 2} 
}
```